# How to skip phrase only if it exists

Tags: regex

I've been cutting my teeth on regex over the past couple of days, and have encountered an issue I cant seem to get past.

Lets assume the following 3 string values

```
AKA NAME:FOO
FOO
AKA NAME:
```

My goal is to capture the value of the string after AKA NAME: in a named match group, and if AKA NAME: is not present, capture the entire string in the match group.  If "AKA NAME:" IS present with no subsequent value, the regex expression should fail. I have developed the following expression

```
^(?:AKA NAME:)?\s*(?<VALUE>(.|\n|\r){1,225})$
```

This will correctly capture the word "FOO" in the first 2 strings above, however, in the third it captures "AKA NAME:" in the match group.  I figured putting ? after the non-capture group containing "AKA NAME:" would have caused the engine to skip this value, but it is not.

Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a look behind assertion and then exclusion set for "AKA NAME:" only:

EDITTED:

`(?<=AKA NAME:)\s?(\w+)|(?!AKA NAME:)^(\w+)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zF7nS6/2)

Comment: NOTE: I am using python, what format are your regex?

Comment: I'm using .net.  This expression was just what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
(?:AKA NAME:)*(.+)*
```

and check if $1 exist.
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zF7nS6/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this regex:

```
"^(AKA NAME\s*:)?\s*(.*)$"gm
```

and get `\2` for your result.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/vC5xC2/1)

Answer (score 0):

`^(AKA NAME:)?(.*)$`

`\2` should contain what you're looking for.